# Permission denied when accessing navigator.userAgent in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a puzzling problem: this seemingly simple page doesn't work in IE9:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <!-- jq.js is the non-minified jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').append('<h1>ok</h1>');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The behaviour I get is that *sometimes* the page displays "ok", and *sometimes* it doesn't display anything. I have found out that it depends on how fast the computer is. If you're on a fast computer, it usually works, but on slow computers, it fails around 2 out of 3 times.

When I look in the debugging console, the symptom is that jQuery gets a permission denied when trying to access `navigator.userAgent`.

The browser writes (in the log) that it is switching from `quirks` mode to `IE9` mode. My hypothesis has been that jQuery is being loaded before the browser switches to `IE9` mode, causing jQuery to be caught in the `quirks` mode and from there on unable to access any browser attributes.

I have tried inserting `<!doctype html>` and inserted the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag to make IE9 switch to `IE9` mode right away, but it didn't fix the problem.

I have managed to leave out jQuery and reproduce the issue with this simple snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<h1>testing</h1>');
        try {
            document.write('<h1>' + navigator.userAgent + '</h1>');
            document.write('<h1>ok</h1>');
        } catch(e) {
            document.write('<h1>not ok</h1>');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(Available at http://test.m.e17.dk/ie9-navigator/.)

Reproduce it by:

1. Open the page.
2. Press F5.
3. Place cursor in address bar.
4. Press enter.

Repeat steps 2-4 as often as desired. Could the issue arise from not waiting for the DOM to load (as said in http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282).

Comment: Remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from the top.

Comment: ...but the page should either start with ``<!doctype html>`` (tried at no avail) or an XML declaration like this one...?

Comment: Did you have you the `<!doctype html>` **instead** of the XML tag?

Comment: Here is an easy way to reproduce the issue. Go to http://test.m.e17.dk/jquery-not-loading/. Press F5. Now select the url in the address bar and press enter. Repeating by pressing F5 followed by enter will reproduce again. (I have modified the example to use ``<!doctype html>`` in stead of the XML declaration.) Remember that it is only defunct in IE9.

Comment: Nope, could not reproduce. Looks like a local problem with your own browser.

Comment: Did you try http://test.m.e17.dk/ie9-navigator/ as well?

Comment: Yes same thing - works without any problem. Try checking from a different machine.

Comment: Thanks, @ShadowWizard. I have found the cause of the error. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the cause of this error: it was a group policy setting in Active Directory that caused IE9 to misbehave. I'll try to get the exact name and add it here for anyone who'd encounter the same issue.

Thanks to everyone helping out.

The policy in question is in the attached picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about 1.9 but I had a similar regression with 1.8 on IE9 (regression over 1.7). The bug is described in details here:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282

Basically the DOM might not be ready when document.ready is fired in IE9, because your javascript script might start before the whole page is read.

Apparently there's actually a debate on how this is a bug or not.

Anyway, updating to 1.8.2 solved my issue. I hope for you the same fix is available for the 1.9 branch, if it's really the same bug you're experiencing.

An alternative solution is to simply move the document.ready part as far as possible at the end of the page, after everything you need from the html (of course in your simplified example it won't work because you use `<body>`, but hopefully in your real code you don't need it).

Alternatively, if you want to get your hands dirty and it hasn't been fixed in 1.9, here's where the fix has been implemented for 1.8:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/0f553ed0ca0c50c5f66377e9f2c6314f822e8f25

As you can see, it's just one line of code, so maybe you can maintain your own fixed version of the 1.9 version until there's a stable release, or maybe you can implement this same safeguard in your own jquery script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion, have you tried to download both scripts from the same content delivery network?, and just make sure that the order is correct, (yours seems right) but it may also be due to latency from one origin or the other. Sidenote: try to put your script tags in the bottom of your documents,rather than the header, this is due to performance issues.

Comment: Yes. The original code where the regression started is using the jQuery CDN.

Comment: I'll just try the example with CDN too.